# How to get min date and max date if results remain unchanged

Tags: sql, inner-join, teradata, row-number, scd

I have an address SCD type 2 table but sometimes information entered remain the same I want to write a query that if information is unchanged, retain the previous begin data and set end date to max e.g

---

```
OBJID          BEGDA      ENDDA     HASHROW_COL RK 
83022088    2012-03-30  2012-10-28  e1-ef-a9-36 1 
83022088    2012-10-29  2013-09-07  63-69-e5-25 2 
83022088    2013-09-08  2014-08-30  e1-ef-a9-36 3
83022088    2014-08-31  2016-11-26  e1-ef-a9-36 4
83022088    2016-11-27  9999-12-31  e1-ef-a9-36 5
```

---

Notice that from rows 3 – 5 the HASHROW_COL remain the same.

---

```
Desired result:
OBJID          BEGDA       ENDDA    HASHROW_COL RK 
83022088    2012-03-30  2012-10-28  e1-ef-a9-36 1 
83022088    2012-10-29  2013-09-07  63-69-e5-25 2
83022088    2013-09-08  9999-12-31  e1-ef-a9-36 3
```

---

Query so far

```
select a.objid, a.hashrow_col, 
case when a.objid <> b.objid then b.begda
    when a.hashrow_col = b.hashrow_col and (b.begda - interval '1' day <= a.endda) then 
    a.begda  end,
case when a.objid <> b.objid then b.endda
    when (a.hashrow_col = b.hashrow_col) and (b.begda - interval '1' day <= a.endda) and b.endda > a.endda  
    then b.endda 
    end,
from
(select objid, begda, endda, HASHROW_COL, 
from OTABLE )  a
inner join 
(select objid, begda, endda, HASHROW_COL, 
from OTABLE) b
on
a.objid = b.objid
where 
and a.objid = '83022088' 
order by a.OBJID, a.BEGDA,  a.HASHROW_COL;
```

Comment: Are `HASHROW_COL `&  `RK` calculated columns (to simplify the logic)? Do you want to fix the data in the SCD table or select those normalized rows? Then it's probably a simple `select normalize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [NORMALIZE](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/2_MC9vCtAJRlKle2Rpb0mA/UuxiA0mklFgv~33X5nyKMA) function and the period data type.

We have to convert your start and end dates to a period.  One gotcha with normalize to work is that consecutive end and start dates must overlap, that's why I've added 1 day to the end date (unless it's 9999-12-31').

```
select normalize on meets or overlaps objid,hashrow_col,duration from (
select
t.*,
period(begda, case when endda = '9999-12-31' then endda else endda +interval '1' DAY end) as duration
from
<your table> t) tt
```

Normalize and period are extremely powerful in the right circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, I would use:

```
select objid, min(begda), max(endda), HASHROW_COL,
       row_number() over (partition by objid order by min(begda)) as ranking
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_endda = begda - interval '1' day then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by objid order by begda) as grouping
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(endda) over (partition by objid, HASHROW_COL order by begda) as prev_endda
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by grouping, objid, HASHROW_COL;
```

Comment: i dont think this is a gaps and islands problem, the value of hashrow_col can be used to get the start and end of the group?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph . . . I see duplicate values on rows 1 and 3, but perhaps I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the hashrow_col is the value which remains the same,(ie you got the values you need to group by) then all you would need is the min(begda) and max(endda)

```
select objid, min(begda) as begda, max(endda) as enddat, HASHROW_COL,
       min(rnk) 
  from OTABLE
group by objid,hashrow_col
```

Comment: It needs to be "gaps and islands", because values (and HASHROW_COL) can potentially be changed back to an earlier value.

Comment: You are correct. The answer i have given wouldnt work in those scenarios.